HttpPostedFIleBase is always null, but other values come in
I've researched all the other posts like this and I'm still so stuck. I'm trying to post the name, pronunciation, bio, website, and image and everything but the image is coming through - it's always null. I have the HttpPostedFileBase matching the name "ImageFile", I'm using FormMethod.Post in my BeginForm, and @enctype = "multipart/form-data".
I thought maybe it would be because my controller takes in ArtistViewModel model and Artist _Artist, but when it gets to this part both have all the values just fine except the image is null.
Any help is appreciated, I've been on this far too long. TIA
ArtistsController.cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(
    ArtistViewModel model,
    Artist _Artist)
{
       
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 
        using (var auditingLogger = new AuditingLogger())
        {
            try
            {
                var userName = User.Identity.Name;
                var user = await _db.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == userName);
                if (user == null) throw new Exception("Authorization failed for User.");

                if (_db.Artists.Any(a => a.IsActive && a.ArtistName == _Artist.ArtistName && a.CreatedByUserId == int.Parse(user.Id)))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Artist already exists for this account.");
                    return View("Create");
                }

                //  Upload Artist Image.
                try
                {
                    var artistImageFileName = user.Id.ToString() + "-" +  model.ImageFile.FileName;
                    var fileUploadResult = await AWSS3Uploader.UploadFile(
                        artistImageFileName,
                        "images",
                        model.ImageFile.InputStream,
                        model.ImageFile.ContentType);
                    auditingLogger.CreateNew().Trace("File " + model.ImageFile.FileName + " uploaded to AWS S3.  " + fileUploadResult);
                    _Artist.ImageFilename = artistImageFileName;

                }
                catch { }
                //  Save Artist record to DB.
                _Artist.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;

                _Artist.CreatedByUserId = int.Parse(user.Id);

                _Artist.IsActive = true;

                _db.Artists.Add(_Artist);

                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

                ViewBag.Status = "Artist, " + _Artist.ArtistName + " has been created successfully.";
                return View("CreateSuccessful", new CreateArtistSuccessfulViewModel() { CreateSuccessfulViewModel = new CreateSuccessfulViewModel() { ObjectName = "Artist", ObjectIdField = "ArtistId", ObjectId = _Artist.ArtistId } });
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                auditingLogger.CreateNew().Error(ex);
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    ViewBag.CreatedByUserId = new SelectList(_db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "AspNetUserId", _Artist.CreatedByUserId);
    return View(model);
}

ArtistViewModel.cs
    public class ArtistViewModel : Artist
    {

        public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
        
        public ArtistViewModel() { }


        public ArtistViewModel(
            Artist _Artist)
        {
            ArtistId = _Artist.ArtistId;
            ArtistName = _Artist.ArtistName;
            ArtistNamePronunciation = _Artist.ArtistNamePronunciation;
            Bio = _Artist.Bio;
            CreatedAt = _Artist.CreatedAt;
            CreatedByUserId = _Artist.CreatedByUserId;
            ImageFilename = _Artist.ImageFilename;
            ImageThumbnailFilename = _Artist.ImageThumbnailFilename;
            LabelArtists = _Artist.LabelArtists;
            pre_migration_record = _Artist.pre_migration_record;
            Songs = _Artist.Songs;
            User = _Artist.User;
            UserArtists = _Artist.UserArtists;
            Website = _Artist.Website;
            IsActive = _Artist.IsActive;
        }

    }
}

_ArtistForm.cshtml
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-7">

        <div class="form-group  label-floating">
            <label class="control-label" for="ArtistName">Artist Name</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ArtistName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArtistName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group label-floating">
            <label class="control-label" for="ArtistNamePronunciation">Artist Name Pronunciation</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ArtistNamePronunciation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArtistNamePronunciation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Website, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Website, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Website, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Bio, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Bio, new {  @class = "form-control", rows = "6" } )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Bio, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="fileinput fileinput-new text-center" data-provides="fileinput">
            <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="max-width:410px">
                @if (ViewBag.Image != null)
                {         
                    <img src="data:image;base64,@ViewBag.Image">
                }
                else
                {
                <img src="/Content/img/image_placeholder.jpg" alt="...">
                }
            </div>
            <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width:410px"></div>
            <div>
                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                    <span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span>
                    <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>             
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImageFile, htmlAttributes: new { @type = "file", @accept = @"image/*", name = "ImageFile"})
                </span>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Remove</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageFile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    </div>

Create.cshtml
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add New Artist";
}
<div class="container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm(actionName: "Create", controllerName: "Artists", method: FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Artists/_ArtistForm.cshtml", Model)
            </div>
            <footer>
                <input type="submit" value="Add New Artist" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </footer>
        </div>
    }
</div>


mmm, everything checks out and your checking the right things. I would probably check the html just to make sure that looks ok. It looks like you might be doing  something with some javascript upload - so maybe an idea would be to go back to basics. Create a standard input outside the partial and just an extra input of the same name in the controller / action. See if it picks it up.
